# Switching Channels Doesn't Show Anything Agora Swift

Tags: swift, agora.io

I am trying to switch channels but the remote video won't show anything for both when it calls switch channel. Join channel works initially but if I try leaving channel and joining channel instead of switching it won't work either. The listener works. I have added the code below. import UIKit import AgoraRtcKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var remoteView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var localView: UIView!

var agoraKit: AgoraRtcEngineKit!

func initializeAgoraEngine() {
    agoraKit = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: AppID, delegate: self)
}

func setupVideo() {
    agoraKit.enableVideo()  // Enables video mode.
    agoraKit.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(
        AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration(size: AgoraVideoDimension640x360,
                                  frameRate: .fps15,
                                    bitrate: AgoraVideoBitrateStandard,
                            orientationMode: .adaptative)
    ) // Default video profile is 360P
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    initializeAgoraEngine()
    setupVideo()
    setupLocalVideo()
    setUpChannel()
}

func setupLocalVideo() {
    let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
    videoCanvas.uid = 0
    videoCanvas.view = localView
    videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
    agoraKit.setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas)
}

func setUpChannel() {
    agoraKit.setDefaultAudioRouteToSpeakerphone(true)
    agoraKit.joinChannel(byToken: nil, channelId: User.current.uid, info:nil, uid:0) {(sid, uid, elapsed) -> Void in
    }
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
}

func switchChannel(channel: String) {
    agoraKit.switchChannel(byToken: nil, channelId: channel, joinSuccess: nil)
}

func leaveChannel() {
    agoraKit.leaveChannel(nil)
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
    remoteView.removeFromSuperview()
    localView.removeFromSuperview()
}

@IBAction func didClickSwitchCameraButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    agoraKit.switchCamera()
}

func addLiveUserAndListener() {
    //listener for channel
}

extension ViewController: AgoraRtcEngineDelegate {
func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, firstRemoteVideoDecodedOfUid uid:UInt, size:CGSize, elapsed:Int) {
    if (remoteView.isHidden) {
        remoteView.isHidden = false
    }
    let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
    videoCanvas.uid = uid
    videoCanvas.view = remoteView
    videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
    agoraKit.setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas)
}

internal func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didOfflineOfUid uid:UInt, reason:AgoraUserOfflineReason) {
    self.remoteView.isHidden = true
}

func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didVideoMuted muted:Bool, byUid:UInt) {
    remoteView.isHidden = muted
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html#//api/name/switchChannelByToken:channelId:joinSuccess:) for the `switchChannel` function, you may note this:

> Note: This method applies to the audience role in the live interactive streaming channel only.

I would recommend for your use case that you call leaveChannel and joinChannel yourself.

As a sidenote, `firstRemoteVideoDecodedOfUid` is deprecated, and you should be using [`didJoinedOfUid`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Protocols/AgoraRtcEngineDelegate.html#//api/name/rtcEngine:didJoinedOfUid:elapsed:) or [`remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Protocols/AgoraRtcEngineDelegate.html#//api/name/rtcEngine:remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid:state:reason:elapsed:) instead.